# Связь выделительных запятых с логическим ударением

Tags: пунктуация

— Было ли вчера оборудование под запись? 
— Вчера, как обычно, БЫЛО, а сегодня — не знаю.

— Как температура?
— Вчера, как ОБЫЧНО, было, а сегодня — не знаю.

Зависят ли выделительные запятые вокруг оборота "как обычно" от логического ударения?

Comment: Температура, наверно, был**а**.

Comment: Здесь не имеет значения род. Имеется в виду такое предложение: Мне вчера как обычно было.

Answer (score 1):

Да, зависят. Если ударение падает на "*было*", то запятые ставятся.

Во втором примере запятые не нужны, так как при изъятии оборота нарушается смысл. А ударение падает на оборот, а не на глагол.

Answer (score 0):

Дело не в логическом ударении. Если "как обычно" употреблено в значении вводного слова, оно обособляется. Если это часть сказуемого, то не обособляется. Проверить легко - если эти слова можно убрать без особой потери смысла, то это вводное слово. Из первого примера убрать можно, из второго - нет.