# Предложение с оборотом "как обычно"

Tags: стилистика, вводные-слова

Говорят, что разобраться с этим оборотом  (а наверное, и вообще с любыми вводными словами) можно без особых проблем, по очень простому правилу.

Цитирую: "Проверить легко ― если эти слова можно убрать без особой потери смысла, то это вводное слово. Из первого примера убрать можно, из второго ― нет".  Из вопроса: [Связь выделительных запятых с логическим ударением](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/457928/%D0%A1%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%81-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC/457932#457932)

Но вот как разобраться с приведенным ниже предложением?

К придаточному или главному предложению относится вводное сочетание *как обычно*? Кстати, неопределенность ― это стилистическая погрешность.

А если к главному, то от причастного оборота его надо обособлять?

А вот и предложение:

*Когда, прослушав, мы с Галиной сели ужинать, **как обычно,** погружённые в мягкую тишину и приглушённый свет её парижской столовой, она посмотрела на меня лукаво и как-то грустно..*.[Сати Спивакова. Не всё (2002)]

Comment: Вы часто делаете одну ошибку. Прочитайте § 202: http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/rules/165-oszp

Comment: А сказать словами никак невозможно? Или исправить хотя бы один раз? Или всё-таки удобно вывесить в качестве объявления?

Comment: Я говорил уже словами, но вы не отреагировали. Значит, не поверили. Значит, нужно тыкнуть правило. (Если в скобках полноценное предложение - точка ставится перед скобкой, как и другие знаки.)

Comment: Тыкнули?  Проявили "вежливость"?  Только говорить вам спасибо почему-то не хочется, впрочем, как и говорить что-то еще. Мне такое оформление кажется нелогичным. Я и так вижу, что предложение самостоятельное, а точка  должна стоять в конце самостоятельной записи, а не самостоятельного предложения. Графически это выглядит очень  неприятно, просто вызывающе. Больше вообще не буду писать "самостоятельные предложения".ТЫКНУТЬ


сов. неперех. разг.-сниж.

То же, что: ткнуть (1).

Ефремова. Толковый словарь Ефремовой. 2012

Comment: Да нормальное слово. Ну чуть резкое. У нас тут не дипломатический разговор. Люди сейчас не общаются исключительно культурными словами. Вы как будто живёте в мире суперкультурных слов. Если кто-то не верит, то часто говорят "тыкнуть доказательство". Точка именно перед скобкой. Нет ни единого примера, где предложение начинается в скобках, а точка после. Это категорически запрещается. Скобки не нуждаются в точке. Правило с Грамоты: **Точка, знаки вопросительный и восклицательный и многоточие ставятся перед закрывающей скобкой, если относятся только к словам, заключенным в скобки.** И пример есть.

Comment: Слово неуместное, форма его имеет пометку "сниженная лексика" (ткнуть - нейтр.),  да и сам ваш менторский тон тоже неуместен. Ваши предыдущие сообщения на эту тему я не видела, а ошибку вы могли исправить молча, так как эта точка не тема вопроса. И не надо мне ничего доказывать: оформительские правила не обсуждаются, а принимаются к исполнению.  Я просто высказала свое мнение об этом правиле.

Comment: Исправить ошибку молча можно, если это единичная случайность. Иначе лучше сказать, как правильно. Правило очень логичное. Раз предложение началось внутри скобок, то должно в них же и закончится (а точка - конец предложения). То есть начало предложения - не скобка, а большая буква. Точка - атрибут не записи, а предложения. В редакции словаря Ефремовой, что у меня, нет пометки *сниж.* Значение из словаря Кузнецова: *Указывать кому-либо на что-либо, обращать чьё-либо внимание на кого-либо или на что-либо (обычно с порицанием).* (У меня без порицания.) Что плохого?

Comment: Точка должна стоять в конце, это АКСИОМА. Точка - это ГРАНИЦА двух сообщений. После точки следует начало следующего сообщения. А ваши логичные скобки обволакивают предложение, так что оно как бы парит в пространстве,  и  говорят о том, что его бы надо вычеркнуть, да не хочется тетрадку пачкать. Такая логика вам понятна, товарищ исполнитель? Если бы точку вынесли за скобки, вы с таким же энтузиазмом доказывали бы правильность этого решения.

Comment: Так говорите - без порицания?  Ну ладно. Только тогда напишите объяснительную записку, чтобы я (и другие) не думали, что с порицанием.

Comment: Нет, честно говоря, я всегда так писал, не читая правило - это казалось мне аксиомой. А потом случайно на него наткнулся. Скобки - это знак вставки (в предложение или - в нашем случае - в текст). Они сами по себе разграничитель (вспомните, что они не требуют запятых, а, по сути, заменяют их). У вас предложение разорвано скобкой. Тогда уже лучше две точки поставить: закрывающую предложение и закрывающую скобки.

Answer (score 1):

Может быть и без запятой:
*Когда, прослушав, мы с Галиной сели ужинать как обычно.* || Ужинать по-обычному, в обычном, привычном порядке (тесная связь со сказуемым).

Неестественно звучит отношение к первой части (было бы перед глаголом). К причастному обороту — нормально. Если задумывалось отношение к первой части, то тогда причастный оборот совсем не в тему.

Думаю, что сюда может распространяться следующее правило:
Если вводное слово (сочетание) стоит в начале или в конце обособленного оборота (обособления, уточнения, пояснения, присоединения), то никаким знаком препинания от оборота оно не отделяется:
*Запасы были сложены в домике, очевидно подвергавшемся нашествию крыс.

Он вспоминал эти слова, возможно слышанные в детстве.

Мимо пробежал кто-то, по счастью нас не заметивший.

Это был разговор, бесспорно выходящий за рамки обыкновенной беседы.*
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122

Comment: Думаете, что распространяется? Вводное сочетание включает сравнительный союз КАК, здесь нужно особое правило. Или хотя бы примеры.

Comment: Не думаю, что дело только в вводном. Тогда это не понятно. Дело в структуре - обособление в начале обособления не делается. Скорее всего, такая закономерная появилась в языке как раз для устранения неопределённости.

Comment: "Как обычно погружённые в мягкую тишину и приглушённый свет её парижской столовой, мы сели ужинать".  Или: Он наконец приехал, как обычно недовольный всем.Здесь вопрос общего плана: может ли оборот относится к другому обособленному обороту и обособляться вместе с ним?

Answer (score 1):

Розенталь:
Сравнительный оборот, находящийся в середине предложения, не выделяется запятыми с двух сторон, а отделяется одной запятой, если нужно показать, к какой части предложения он относится, например:
*Я мчался на лихом коне, как ветер волен и один* (не «мчался, как ветер», а «волен и один, как ветер»).
*Я почувствовал на моих волосах прикосновение слабой, как лист дрожавшей руки* [Тургенев] («дрожавшей, как лист», а не «слабой, как лист»).
*Зацепившись за что-то платьицем, маленькая девочка, хорошенькая и нарядная, как кукла распласталась* (сравнительный оборот отнесен не к предыдущей, а к последующей части предложения).

В данных примерах тоже присутствуют обособленные обороты. А первый пример даже совпадает по структуре с предложением Спиваковой:
*Подлежащее => сказуемое => сравнительный оборот => обособленное определение (относящееся к подлежащему).*

Answer (score 0):

Даже если слепо пользоваться этим правилом (не берусь судить о его всеобщности), трудно проигнорировать в нём слово **смысл**. При внимательном отношении к смыслу трудно усмотреть в этом предложении "тесную связь" выражения "как обычно" с чем-то к нему примыкающим. Например, чтобы приписать некое "обыкновение" способу сесть поужинать, нужен другой контекст или хотя бы другой порядок слов; слово "сесть" препятствует даже попыткам намеренной организации такой "связи", проще в этих целях обойтись без него:

> *Ужинали* мы с Галиной в тот вечер [как?] *как обычно*, [или тире здесь] без какой-либо
>   осетрины, чёрной икры и ананасов в шампанском.

Ещё менее вероятен смысл, что "обыкновенным образом" за ужином всякий раз происходило "погружение  в мягкую тишину" (второе примыкание к выражению "как обычно"), что в результате и позволяет в этом предложении уверенно полагать "как обычно" **вводным** выражением, с соответствующей его статусу пунктуацией. Другое дело - зачем было автору к сообщению "как обычно, (вечером) мы сели поужинать" присоединять "погружённость в мягкую тишину", но уже вопрос стиля, а не *смысла*.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение. Мне всегда нравится стиль вашей речи, но я часто не могу понять окончательный смысл. 1) Вы не могли бы в начале ответа приводить вариант предложения, который вы считаете правильным.  2)  Мне хотелось бы еще ссылку на правило, где обособляется подобный оборот (с союзом КАК или другим союзом), стоящий в начале причастного или деепричастного оборота.  Именно союз не дает возможности точно определить статус оборота. Обычно вводные слова не обособляются, если они тесно примыкают к обороту, входят в его состав или могут считаться присоединительными . союзами.