# Вводное слово перед обособленным оборотом

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова

По современным правилам вводное слово не отделяется от обособленного оборота запятой, но, может быть, это правило имеет исключения?

Вот два примера из книги Б. Акунина:

*Но в ста шагах от лицея Ластика подстерегало еще одно происшествие, **пожалуй, самое удивительное из всех**.*

*Этот день, **наверное, самый важный в истории человечества**, начался обыкновенно.*

Допускается ли такая пунктуация?  Такое обособление вводного слова кажется естественным, а присоединение его  к обороту — **ничем не оправданным, кроме формального правила.**

Как вообще догадаться, что это вводное слово, если его не обособлять?

В Правилах 1956 года вводное слово могло относится только **к уточняющим членами предложения,** при этом оно выполняло функцию присоединительных слов: *Многие наши поэты, например Жуковский, были отличными переводчиками.*

Comment: Это правило малоизвестное. Может, Акунин не знал про него и поставил тире на общих основаниях?

Comment: Это правило вы называете малоизвестным? Розенталь: 4. Если вводное слово (сочетание) стоит в начале или в конце обособленного оборота (обособления, уточнения, пояснения, присоединения), то никаким знаком препинания от оборота оно не отделяется:http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122#pp122  А у Акунина  были корректоры и редакторы, ему-то зачем знать.

Comment: Да знаю, что есть у Розенталя. Просто про вводные слова знают все, а про обособленные обороты - нет. Не вижу других причин.

Comment: По определению, вводные слова не входят в состав предложения. Какое же мы имеем право включать их в оборот? Кроме того, есть парные варианты, когда слово имеет значения наречия, а не вводности. Значит, их уже не различить?А может, это уже и не вводное слово, а наречие?

Comment: Мне тоже это правило не сильно понравилось. Его смысл - точно видеть, к чему относится вводное слово: к обороту или к предыдущей части. А есть примеры, где не различить?

Comment: Да хотя бы слово наверное. У него раньше было еще одно значение: "точно, несомненно".  Это и было наречие. А смысл у этого правила бывает редко, обычно и так  видно, к чему относится вводное слово. И всё-таки интересно: в состав предложения не входит, а в состав оборота входит.

Comment: Но сейчас это только вводное слово. Не слышал, чтобы у кого-то были правила полнее, чем у Розенталя. А у Розенталя исключений нет. Или запятая стоит по незнанию, или это протест против данного правила. Попробуйте спросить у самого Акунина: https://www.facebook.com/borisakunin

Answer (score 2):

> Как вообще догадаться, что это вводное слово, если его не обособлять?

Розенталь:
В некоторых случаях, во избежание неясности, перед вводным словом, находящимся в начале обособленного оборота, ставится запятая и тире, а после него — запятая, т. е. вводное слово выделяется, например: *Поскольку есть время, вызовем на экзамен еще кого-нибудь, — допустим, сдающих повторно* (допустим в значении «предположим», «скажем»). При пунктуации согласно правилу § 78 получилось бы: *...вызовем на экзамен еще кого-нибудь, допустим сдающих повторно* (слово *допустим* могло бы быть воспринято не как вводное, а в значении «допустим к экзамену»).
Иногда для этой цели используется вставная конструкция; ср.:
*Последняя работа труппы, правда в несколько расширенном составе, показывает рост мастерства актеров.

Последняя работа труппы — правда, в несколько расширенном составе — показывает рост мастерства актеров.

Этому фильму, казалось бы классическому воплощению неореализма, не хватает свежести. Этому фильму — казалось бы, классическому воплощению неореализма — не хватает свежести.*
Запятая и тире ставятся также, если в начале обособленного оборота стоит вводное предложение, например:
*Прежде всего об одной развеянной легенде, — хочется думать, развеянной навсегда* (в данном примере играет роль также повторение слова).

Comment: Это всё хорошо и правильно, только не объясняет пунктуацию в приведённых примерах из Акунина. Если вторую цитату ещё более-менее можно подогнать под то, что *наверное* может означать *наверняка*, из-за чего появляется двусмысленность, то в первой цитате сложно уловить хоть какую-то двусмысленность.

Comment: oleedd, а  ссылку на это  правило у вас есть?

Comment: Тут есть: https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=j8i8DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA232&lpg=PA232&dq=Поскольку+есть+время,+вызовем+на+экзамен+еще+кого-нибудь&source=bl&ots=iXY_J9iK4a&sig=ACfU3U3HbU-jQJaNHCAbxJdQVruFVkp-QA&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiGjbClzsvnAhW7zMQBHZucD5gQ6AEwAHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=Поскольку%20есть%20время%2C%20вызовем%20на%20экзамен%20еще%20кого-нибудь

Comment: Ставлю лайк за информацию.

Answer (score 1):

Зачем вообще существует это правило?
Ответ: Чтобы было чётко ясно, к чему относится вводное слово.

Например:
*Он уже вернулся, наверно, уставший, но довольный.* || Наверно, вернулся или, наверно, уставший, но довольный? А вариантов два. И оба верные. Воспринимайте как хотите.

По правилам:
1) *Он уже вернулся, наверно, уставший, но довольный.* || Вводное слово относится к главному предложению.
2) *Он уже вернулся, наверно уставший, но довольный.* || Вводное слово чётко относится к обороту.

> Почему вводные слова не входят в придаточные предложения

В придаточных предложениях двусмысленности, как правило, не возникает.

Comment: Вводное слово ЧЁТКО перестает быть вводным, а выполняет другую функцию, как мне подсказали добрые люди.

Comment: Предпочитаете догадываться, к чему оно больше относится?

Comment: Свое мнение я  обозначила в  комментарии к другому ответу. Не надо всех строить в одну линейку. Если вводное слово может изменить свою функцию и стать присоединительным или усилительным словом, то я не против. Но не все вводные слова могут это сделать.

Comment: У вас же был вопрос про двусмысленность (когда сравнение на границе обособленного оборота). Разве это есть хорошо? https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/457940 Дело ещё в том, что автор может не заметить двусмысленность, которую может заметить читатель.

Comment: Мне бы хотелось, чтобы меня избавили от необходимости присоединять конкретные вводные слова (пожалуй, наверное) к конкретному обособленному обороту.  Здесь нет двусмысленности, поэтому мне не нравится, что это называют ошибкой. По моему мнению, самая грубая грамматическая ошибка - это считать слова вводными, если они изменили свою функцию (если для этого есть основания).

Comment: Вы можете не видеть двусмысленность, а другой заметит. Правила общие - чтобы не было такого, что изучить их в состоянии лишь избранные.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение. Чтобы было поменьше избранных, грамотных и не в меру утонченных, надо вообще все правила максимально упростить. Тогда уж точно они выделяться на общем фоне не будут, и грамотность повысится. Я удивляюсь, как  орфографическая система  до сих пор еще выдерживает давление со стороны подобных реформаторов - сохраняет гибкость русской речи и наш духовный потенциал.

Comment: Розенталь знал 12 языков и говорил, что русский - самый сложный. При этом он сравнивал его и с другими языками, про которые знал. Куда уж его ещё-то усложнять? Писатели не захотели, потому что двусмысленность - понятие относительное. Более того, даже чуть-чуть анализировать, куда относится элемент, во время чтения - не лучшее занятие. Так книги придётся читать очень долго

Comment: Знаете, как человек видит предметы? Он не рассматривает все детали последовательно (на это ушло бы много времени), поэтому сканируется несколько самых важных. В письменной речи так же.  Вы думаете, я не догадаюсь, что "пожалуй" относится ко второй части, буду долго думать над этим вопросом. Нет, я буду долго думать, если не увижу. привычного обособления. Поэтому людям с их "механистическим" мышлением надо категорически запретить заниматься составлением правил. А Розенталь тут ни при чем. Его или редактировали, или вынудили  к этому вышестоящие авторитеты.

Comment: Да нет, так писали и Достоевский, и Горький, и Островский, и Толстой. Это правило присутствует и в оригинальных изданиях справочников. А авторитетов выше Розенталя не было, если не считать власть, которой заняться больше нечем, как получать выгоду от изменения пунктуационных правил.

Comment: Я не вижу этого правила в сборнике 1956 года (вернее, там у него другая редакция), а это официально утвержденный справочник, в отличие от всех других. Приведите примеры из классиков. Кстати, проведение орфографической реформы в 2001 году остановили очень влиятельные люди.

Comment: Или лучше так: задайте вопрос о классиках на форуме. А то вся эта информация уйдет в чат.

Comment: Не знаю, какой вопрос задавать, но примеры классиков есть в самом правиле (сокращения легко расшифровываются). Остановили, потому что люди не любят, когда меняется то, к чему все привыкли. Люди бы, скорее всего, просто проигнорировали эту реформу, как происходит в Украине (хотя через СМИ активно пытаются продвигать новшества в массы). Другое дело - изменить некоторые сложные слова или разрешить спорные случаи.

Comment: Ладно, спасибо, закроем тему.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, что конкретно эти примеры можно объяснить одним из двух вариантов:

1. Ошибка редактора/корректора. Больше тут сказать нечего.
2. Намеренное и осознанное отступление Б. Акуниным от современной нормы, то есть *авторская пунктуация*. Действительно ли это является особенностью пунктуации Акунина и насколько часто это отступление встречается в его текстах, могут сказать только поклонники его творчества.

Comment: Да, об этом я уже сказал в комментариях.

Comment: Да, я видел. Но это не обязательно протест. Возможно, это ссылка на дореволюционную пунктуацию (не берусь утверждать, что так писали раньше, но вдруг), либо обосновано какими-то другими соображениями. Либо см. пункт 1.

Comment: Интересное предположение про 2, но это вряд ли, потому что у Розенталя есть примеры авторов, живших до революции: Достоевский, Горький, Островский, Толстой. Ну, дважды ошибиться не могли (здесь простой пример данного правила), но теоретически могли просто не знать о самом правиле.

Comment: Ну, тогда Акунину (или издательству) можно только посоветовать уволить таких корректоров. Можно простить незнание этого правила школьнику или человеку «с улицы», но не специалисту, профессионально работающему с текстом.

Comment: Этот роман Акунина, вероятно, издавался много раз (у меня бумажный экземпляр 2008 года), поэтому с ней работали многие редакторы и корректоры, но вроде бы никто и ничего не исправил. Книгу можно почитать онлайн: https://nice-books.ru/books/detskaya-literarura/detskie-prikluchenija/215453-boris-akunin-detskaya-kniga.html Авторская пунктуация? Тоже сомнительно. При случае добавлю примеры из других произведений, а вдруг это "всеобщая авторская пунктуация".

Comment: @Sharon Да тут не особо-то много вариантов. Это либо непреднамеренное отступление от нормы, и тогда это ошибка (по незнанию или по случайности); либо намеренное и умышленное написание, и тогда это авторская пунктуация. В любом случае такая пунктуация не соответствует действующим нормам русского языка. Приводимые у Розенталя примеры говорят о том, что это не «всеобщая» пунктуация. Если же такая постановка запятой действительно распространена у современных авторов, то, возможно, мы наблюдаем смещение нормы. Но пока оно не зафиксировано в правилах, такое написание следует считать ошибкой.

Comment: Я бы ошибкой считала само правило, так как это отклонение от правил 1956 года. А сейчас это выглядит как возвращение к норме. Во вы, к примеру, можете объяснить, как вводное слово может не входить в предложение (по определению), но при этом входит в оборот. Почему вводные слова не входят в придаточные предложения и даже способствуют расчленению составного союза. Нет в этом правиле  ни логики, ни смысла.  Валгина в 2004 году писала, что нормы могут отставать от практики. Кроме авторской пунктуации, она выделяет еще и ситуативную, и это не ошибка, а свидетельство интуиции и культуры речи.

Comment: @Sharon Вообще-то нет, это не противоречит правилам 1956 года. Вот, например: http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/rules/153-zap-19-34, примечание 3. А насчёт логики и смысла я больше доверяю специалистам по языку, чем современным писателям, уж извините.

Comment: Да пожалуйста - как сказал поэт, "каждый выбирает для себя..."  В то же время можно заметить, что необособленные вводные слова уже не являются вводными, и об этом написано в правилах 1956 года. Она приобретают другую функцию, если могут это сделать. Так что это не их всеобщая обязанность. Вот слово "например" умеет это делать, а слова "пожалуй и наверное" - вряд ли.