# Можно ли поставить запятую в сочетании "выглядеть как"?

Tags: пунктуация, оборот-с-как

*Он с любопытством открыл якобы книжку. *Внутри она **выглядела, как** самый обыкновенный учебник: задачки, чертежи, теоремы.* Потрогал страницу – бумага как бумага* (Б. Акунин).

Как можно объяснить обособление оборота в роли обстоятельства, тесно связанного со сказуемым?

**ВЫГЛЯДЕТЬ**,  нсв. Иметь тот или иной вид; восприниматься каким-л. образом. Хорошо в. В. усталым, больным. Как я выгляжу? Показания выглядели правдиво. Комната выглядела уютно.

Comment: Не первый раз этот писатель игнорирует правила: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/458283

Comment: И здесь отступает от правил: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/461083

Comment: Докажите, что отступает.  Четко,  по правилу. И диалектику тесной связи тоже раскройте – любопытно, знаете ли....  Как это конкретно выглядит, какими формальными средствами обозначено.  Может, это такой распространенный оборот, что особо тесно его к сказуемому и не привяжешь.  Мне в настоящий момент редакторы представляются мучителями поэтов и истинных художником слова, и никак иначе.

Comment: Что за диалектика? Сейчас не любят ставить тире перед "это". Что тут доказывать? Подобных исключений в правилах нет. Без тире получается следующее: *Во-первых, что меня поразило, [так] это пассажиры.* Там такой смысл? Тогда после "первое" должно быть двоеточие. "Так" в таких случаях нежелательно опускать. Эх, любите вы ошибки оправдывать, все писатели у вас безгрешны.

Comment: Знаете, есть такой термин (в вузовском учебнике),  который называется несвободные (фразеологизованныее) конструкции. То есть это  ряд несвободных моделей, которые моно отнести к нестандартным и нечастотным.  Тем не менее они встречаются, причем часто в разговорной речи. Вы же  не хотите их изучать, вам легче их выбросить и зачеркнуть., чем отнестись бережно, внимательно и с любовью. Мысль понятна?

Comment: Давайте примеры, которые "мне легче выбросить и зачеркнуть".

Comment: Дайте да подайте, а у меня времени не хватает. Дел много, а помощников нет. Учебник возьмите и сами прочитайте.  А если случайно увижу, то скажу. ОК?

Comment: Ок. Я против ошибок (таких, как у Акунина), так что против ваших правильных примеров с учебников, скорее всего, не буду.